# Visual Studio SSDT Lookup data types do not match

Tags: sql, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to create a lookup for 2 tables. One of the 2 values I am trying to connect is a varchar and the other one is a nvarchar. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Im trying to connect item_storage_type to Type. The problem is that item_storage_type is a nvarchar(50) and the Type is a varchar(50). Is it possible to connect them?

```
Cannot map the input column, 'item_storage_type', to the lookup column, 'Type', because the data types do not match.
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll either need to CAST/CONVERT that in your source (or lookup) query or add a Data Transformation task to convert it to the appropriate type. The data types need to match for SSIS to do the lookup.